# how to include and execute php variable with html and other php variables in it

Tags: php, variables, include, execute

I'm stuck...
I have a variable which has html (sometimes javascript) and php code (other variables) in it and is stored in a mysql db.
Basically, what I have to do is insert the variable into a page -> what works but the php code is not executed its just displayed like txt. So I am looking for a way to insert the variable so that the php code is recognized and executed (the vars are inserted)..

What I tried so far:
(very simple) Sample code stored in db:

Image Var (new_p_img):

```
<a href="product.php"><img src="new.png" alt="New Products" width="250" height="250"></a>
```

Image Display Code Var (new_p_dis):

```
<div class="new-products">
<?php echo $new_p_img; ?>
</div>
```

To display in site I try

```
 <?php echo $new_p_dis; ?>
```

The code is displayed perfectly in source code but the php echo code is not recognized/executed its treated like normal txt.
I also tried to include it thru an extra file.

Sample code new-product.php

```
<?php echo $new_p_img; ?>
```

To display in site I try

```
<?php echo include('products/new-product.php'); ?>
```

didnt work... If i put the "new_p_dis" code direct into the site or the new-product.php file like this

```
<div class="new-products">
<?php echo $new_p_img; ?>
</div>
```

it works fine but than I would have to re-code the entire site..... thats not an option :(

**Is it somehow possible to maybe preload the var "new_p_dis" add the missing "new_p_img" var and then insert the final code into the page?**

A code example would really help me out.

Thx

PS: eval() isnt an option ;)

PPS: The above codes are just a simple sample, the real codes are much more complicated, the vars are all dynamicly created via php and stored in the database -> I only need a starting point :)

Comment: How do you think you are going to execute an arbitrary string without using `eval`? Why are you storing code in your database?

Comment: the code is generated and inserted during import from a "order processing software" and cant be changed.... the direct usage of "eval(the code)" was what i first tried it worked local, but isnt allowed on the hosting plan....

Comment: `eval` is the answer, period. Also, keep in mind "if eval is the answer, you're almost certainly asking the wrong question" (Rasmus Lerdorf).

Answer (score 0):

Actually this does work... with a work around.
What I did was simply creat a function where I grabbed the stored variable, added what I needed and then "called" it in my Page.

```
function main_p_lnk_shortcode() { 
    global $uf_vars;
    $p_lnk1 = '<a href="' . $uf_vars_lnk . '" title="' . $uf_vars_nam . '"><img src="' . $uf_vars_img . '" alt="" /></a>';
    return $p_lnk1;
  }
 add_shortcode('main_p_lnk', 'main_p_lnk_shortcode');
```

In this case I added a WP-ShortCode

I did the same with all other vars that had php tags in them, load, manipulate then return, as direct function or shortcode....